# Violation access in time compilation (0xC0000005)

Tags: c++, access-violation, fftw, itk

The process I want to do is to make the FFT to an image (stored in “imagen”) , and then, multiply it with a filter ‘H’, after that, the inverse FFT will be done also.
The code is shown below:

```
int ancho;
int alto;
ancho=ui.imageframe->imagereader->GetBufferedRegion().GetSize()[0];     //ancho=widht of the image
alto=ui.imageframe->imagereader->GetBufferedRegion().GetSize()[1];      //alto=height of the image

double *H ;
H =matrix2D_H(ancho,alto,eta,sigma); // H is calculated

// We want to get: F= fft(f) ; H*F ; f'=ifft(H*F)
// Inicialization of the neccesary elements for the calculation of the fft
fftw_complex *out;
fftw_plan p;

int N= (ancho/2+1)*alto; //number of points of the image
out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);

double *in = (double*) imagen.GetPointer(); // conversion of itk.smartpointer --> double*
p = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(ancho, alto, in, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE); // FFT planning
fftw_execute(p); // FFT calculation

/* Multiplication of the Output of the FFT with the Filter H*/ 
int a = alto;
int b = ancho/2 +1; // The reason for the second dimension to have this value is that when the FFT calculation of a real image is performed only the non-redundants outputs are calculated, that’s the reason for the output of the FFT and the filter ‘H’ to be equal. 

// Matrix point-by-point multiplicaction: [axb]*[axb]
fftw_complex* res ; // result will be stored here
res = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*a*b);
res = multiply_matrix_2D(out,H, a, b);
```

The problem is located here, in the loop inside the function ‘multiply_matrix_2D’:

```
 fftw_complex*  prueba_r01::multiply_matrix_2D(fftw_complex* out, double* H, int M ,int N){
/* The matrix out[MxN] or [n0x(n1/2)+1] is the image after the FFT , and the out_H[MxN] is the filter in the frequency domain,
both are multiplied POINT TO POINT, it has to be called  twice, one for the imaginary part and another for the normal part
*/
fftw_complex *H_cast;
H_cast = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*M*N);
H_cast= reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*> (H); // casting from double* to fftw_complex*

fftw_complex *res; // the result of the multiplication will be stored here
res = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*M*N);

//Loop for calculating the matrix point-to-point multiplication
for (int x = 0; x<M ; x++){
    for (int y = 0; y<N ; y++){
            res[x*N+y][0] = out[x*N+y][0]*(H_cast[x*N+y][0]+H_cast[x*N+y][1]); 
            res[x*N+y][1] = out[x*N+y][1]*(H_cast[x*N+y][0]+H_cast[x*N+y][1]); 
        }
}
fftw_free(H_cast);
return res;
}
```

With the values of x = 95 and y = 93 being M = 191 and N = 96;
Uncontroled exception at 0x004273ab in prueba_r01.exe: 0xC0000005 acess infraction reading 0x01274000.

[imagen http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/4585/accessviolationproblem.png](http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/4585/accessviolationproblem.png)

Where a lot of values of the variables are in red, and for translation issue: H_cast[][1] has in the value box : “Error30CXX0000 : impossible to evaluate the expression”.

I will really appreciate any kind of help with this please!!

Antonio

Comment: How big is the array itself ? is 95*96+93 larger than the array ? and does it always have 2 other dimensions ? ( [0],[1] )

Comment: H is defined as: " H = (double*) malloc((ancho/2 + 1)*alto*sizeof(double)), therefore, also H_cast will have the same dimension, in particular for this image the dimension is [M=191;N=96].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the code

```
H_cast = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*M*N);
H_cast= reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*> (H); // casting from double* to fftw_complex*
```

first allocates a new buffer for `H_cast` and then immediately sets it to point to the original `H` instead. It doesn't copy the data, just the pointer.

At the end of the function some buffer is free'd

```
fftw_free(H_cast);
```

which seems to free the data pointed to by `H` and not the buffer allocated in the function.

When getting back to the caller, the `H` there is lost!

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)! . The thing is what I have is a matrix with double values inside, but I have to multiply it with a matrix with complex numbers, then, having the pointer to H as fftw_complex also, I can show the directions for doing the multiplication....I think that after doing the multiplication the information that I need is in "res", so I can delete H_cast o even H...am I wrong in what I am saying? Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

There is an FFT class inside of ITK that can use fftw (USE_FFTW) from cmake for configuration.  This class describes how to reference the ITK raw buffer memory from fftw.

PS:  The upcoming ITKv4 has greatly improved the fftw compatibility.